# jQuery JavaScript subclassing and properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, inheritance

I implement a class (I call it RowsEditor) and its subclass (I call it DateRowsEditor) with the jQuery code similar to this:

```
function create_RowsEditor(tableId) {
  var rowsEditor = {
    tableId: tableId,
    quit_row: function(ctl) { /*...*/ }
  };
  $('#'+tableId).click(function(event) {
    var tr = event.delegateTarget;
    rowsEditor.quit_row(tr);
  });
  return rowsEditor;
}

function create_DateRowsEditor(tableId) {
  var rowsEditor = $.extend({}, create_RowsEditor(tableId), {
    quit_row: function(ctl) { /*...*/ }
  };
  return rowsEditor;
}
```

Then I create an object of type DateRowsEditor():

```
var rowsEditor = create_DateRowsEditor('come'):
```

The trouble is that on user's click quit_row() is called with an object created by create_RowsEditor() not with the derived object created with create_DateRowsEditor() as it should.

How to do it properly in a structured and object oriented way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by adding the .init() method:

```
var rowsEditor = {
  tableId: tableId,
  init: function() {
    var self = this;
    $('#'+tableId).handleRowsBlur(function(event) {
      var tr = event.delegateTarget;
      self.quit_row(tr);
    });
    return this;
  },
  ...
```

and creating objects like this:

```
/*var rowsEditor =*/ create_ComeEditor('come').init();
```

It is the proper way to solve my problem because this way initialization of event handlers is called only when it is should be called.

Answer (score 0):

> The trouble is that on user's click quit_row() is not called with the derived object

Then don't use `extend` for that. Just create the object, and overwrite its `quit_row` method:

```
function create_DateRowsEditor(tableId) {
  var rowsEditor = create_RowsEditor(tableId);
  rowsEditor.quit_row = function(ctl) { /*...*/ };
  return rowsEditor;
}
```